# Do you capitalize (A/a)mazon the company?

Tags: capitalization

"amazon" starts with a lower case letter, but usually when I see the name of a company mentioned, it starts with a capital letter like "Google," so do I capitalize it or not?

Comment: "Amazon" is capitalized when it's the name of a river or of a region of Brazil. But even if the company were named for something mundane like "Potatoes, Inc." you would capitalize it as the name of a company.

Comment: For example, *Apple* is capitalized when it's the name of a company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "Amazon" in the company's logo is not capitalized, nonetheless when the company name is used in text it seems to be most often capitalized as would be the name of any other company.

For example, even in the company's own press releases we see the name capitalized:

> Today, Amazon (NASDAQ: AMZN) announced four new renewable energy projects in Australia, Spain, Sweden, and the US that further support Amazon’s commitment to reach 80% renewable energy by 2024 and 100% renewable energy by 2030 on path to net zero carbon by 2040.

([source](https://press.aboutamazon.com/news-releases/news-release-details/amazon-continues-renewable-energy-investments-wind-and-solar))

In cases of companies that prefer their names not be capitalized, it would be a matter of house style rather than English grammar whether to follow the company's wishes or the standard capitalization of proper names.